# Going bonkers over this small code, chrome.runtime.onMessage gives undefined, always. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know there are similar questions and I've tried almost everything in them. I'm trying to build a chrome extension and it needs to pass a message from content.js to background.js.

The code:

background.js

```
var xstext;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {  
      xstext=request.stext;
});


var wtf = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+xstext;
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
      if(command=="ntab"){
         chrome.tabs.create({ url: wtf}); 
      }
  });
```

content.js

```
var text = window.getSelection();
var stext=text.toString();

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({stext: stext});
```

manifest.json

```
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "vind",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Search stuff easily!",

    "background": {

      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },

 "content_scripts": [
  { 

    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],



    "browser_action": {
         "default_icon": {                    
           "16": "images/icon16.png",    
           "32": "images/icon32.png"          
          },

          "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },

  "commands": {
  "ntab": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Alt+G",
      "windows": "Alt+G",
      "mac": "Alt+G",
      "chromeos": "Alt+G",
      "linux": "Alt+G"
    },
  "description": "New tab for the query"
  }
}


}
```

I want to pass the selected text from content.js to background.js, I have tried adding return: true; in the listener to no avail. I'm getting 'undefined' added to the main string, so nothing seems to get passed. what should I do?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your goal is here, but you should probably put the onCommand listener inside the onMessage listener.

Comment: @GergelySzabo, the goal is clear and onCommand should be global, otherwise it won't wake up the event page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach won't work because 1) your content script is saving the text at the moment it runs which happens just one time at page load and 2) since the background script is not persistent it'll unload after receiving a message and xstext will disappear.

Do the reverse: ask the content script when the hotkey is pressed.

background.js, entire contents:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(command => {
  if (command === 'ntab') {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
      if (!tab) return;
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'getText', text => {
        chrome.tabs.create({
          url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(text),
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

content.js, entire contents:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'getText' && document.hasFocus()
  && (!document.activeElement || !/^I?FRAME$/.test(document.activeElement.tagName))) {
    sendResponse(getSelection().toString());
  }
});
```

P.S. An advanced solution would be to run the content script on demand (using chrome.tabs.executeScript in background.js onCommand listener) so you can remove content_scripts section from manifest.json and use [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission instead.

Comment: You're a god amongst men. This solved it. Thank you soooo much!